# Nifi expression - evaluate cron and current timestamp?

Tags: cron, apache-nifi

I know and have used the standard Nifi generateFlowFileProcessor running on a cron schedule. As an example lets assumme my nifi flow will execute a SQL DELETE and INSERT statement for two groups of tables on two schedule times.

The simplest implementation will have two generateFlowFileProcessors running on the different schedules,

```
Nifi Cron Expression -> Group
0 0/15 * * * * ? -> 15min tables schedule
0 0/30 * * * * ? -> 30min tables schedule
```

which load the list tables from a json file which then split to result in each table getting reloaded.

```
{
"tablesToLoad":
    [
        {
        "sourceTable": "TableA",
        "targetTable": "TableB",
        },
        {
        "sourceTable": "TableC",
        "targetTable": "TableD",
        }
    ]
}
```

My problem is this doesn't scale well, if need to add other schedules and more table groups. I need to add more generateFlowFileProcessors and schedules to the flow for each reconfiguration.

My preference is to have a single generateFlowFileProcessor which runs on a 5min schedule. The exact schedule that each table runs will be defined as part of the externally loaded config json blob

```
{
"tablesToLoad":
    [
        {
        "sourceTable": "TableA",
        "targetTable": "TableB",
        "schedule": "0 0/15 * * * * ?"
        },
        {
        "sourceTable": "TableC",
        "targetTable": "TableD",
        "schedule": "0 0/30 * * * * ?"
        },
        {
        "sourceTable": "TableC",
        "targetTable": "TableD",
        "schedule": "0 0 0/5 * * * ?"
        }
    ]
}
```

Given that the flowFile will be generated with a currentTimeStamp, is there a simple or recommended way in which I could evalue the $schedule expression above with the currentTimestamp to determine if the cron expression matches or not?

Comment: Just curious why you decided to use cron? Does it really matter exactly when the 5 minute reloads happen? (Why not simply configure a Nifi processor to run every 5 minutes)

Comment: Readers may note that this has been cross posted to the Cloudera Community (also unanswered at this time) https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Nifi-expression-evaluate-cron-schedule-and-current-timestamp/m-p/298743

Comment: Use regex instead of Cron to match time